# Android manifest package

Tags: android, android-manifest

Зачем этот атрибут в манифесте? - `package`, и что туда нужно писать, а то я вижу люди пишут как хотят

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package - полное имя пакета приложения, которое обычно пишут в формате [обратного DNS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_DNS). Может содержать буквы A-Z, a-z, цифры и нижние подчеркивания. Используется этот атрибут для 2 целей:

- это имя пакета используется как пространство имен для класса `R.java`, который используется для доступа к ресурсам приложения. Например, если имя пакета будет `com.MyCompany.MySuperApp`, то класс `R` будет создан в `com.MyCompany.MySuperApp.R`
- также это имя используется для того, чтобы создать полное имя для сущностей внутри манифеста приложения ( таких как `Activity`, `Service`, `Application`)

В общем случае, имя пакета удобно использовать, чтобы объявив его 1 раз в начале манифеста, не указывать полное имя для всех `Activity`, `Service`, `Application` далее по манифесту.

Пример:

Без указания  имени пакета:

```
<manifest . . . >
<application . . . >
    <service android:name="com.example.project.SecretService" . . . >
        . . .
    </service>
    . . .
</application>
```

С указанием имени пакета:

```
<manifest package="com.example.project" . . . >
<application . . . >
    <service android:name=".SecretService" . . . >
        . . .
    </service>
    . . .
</application>
```

Результат у примеров будет идентичный, только во втором случае не придется каждый раз дублировать имя пакета.

Выбрать себе имя пакета вы можете сами, главное, чтобы оно было уникальным. Одной из частых практик при выборе имени является формат `com.ИмяКомпанииИлиРазработчика.НазваниеПриложения` в таком случае имя является осмысленным (читаемым) и наверняка будет уникальным. Хотя, если не ошибаюсь, формат не обязательно должен быть reverse-DNS.

Подробней можно почитать в [официальной документации по манифесту](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=ru) и конкретно по [атрибуту package](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html?hl=ru#package)